# C++ finding a string in multiple strings

Tags: c++, string, find

I am making a program where you type in a letter combination like 'an' and the program finds countries that contain that two letter sequence. I only want it to search for a two letter combination, but if there's a way to also check for three letter sequences then that would be an added bonus. So far I have a string array, I would like to keep it that way. Here's what I have so far, right now it can only find strings that are the same, because I set it up that way, I want to change it to where it finds countries with the two letter sequence in it. Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {

const int SIZE = 197;

string Countries[SIZE] = {"Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra","Angola","Antigua and Barbuda","Argentina","Armenia","Australia","Austria","Azerbaijan",
                        "Bahamas","Bahrain","Bangladesh","Barbados","Belarus","Belgium","Belize","Benin","Bhutan","Bolivia","Bosnia and Herzegovina","Botswana","Brazil","Brunei","Bulgaria","Burkina Faso","Burundi",
                        "Cambodia","Cameroon","Canada","Cabo Verde","Central African Republic","Chad","Chile","China","Colombia","Comoros","Costa Rica","Cote d'Ivoire","Croatia","Cuba","Cyprus","Czechia",
                        "Democratic Republic of the Congo","Denmark","Djibouti","Dominica","Dominican Republic",
                        "Ecuador","Egypt","El Salvador","Equatorial Guinea","Eritrea","Estonia","Ethiopia",
                        "Fiji","Finland","France",
                        "Gabon","Gambia","Georgia","Germany","Ghana","Greece","Grenada","Guatemala","Guinea","Guinea-Bissau","Guyana",
                        "Haiti","Honduras","Hungary",
                        "Iceland","India","Indonesia","Iran","Iraq","Ireland","Israel","Italy",
                        "Jamaica","Japan","Jordan",
                        "Kazakhstan","Kenya","Kiribati","Kosovo","Kuwait","Kyrgyzstan",
                        "Laos","Latvia","Lebanon","Lesotho","Liberia","Libya","Liechtenstein","Lithuania","Luxembourg",
                        "Macedonia","Madagascar","Malawi","Malaysia","Maldives","Mali","Malta","Marshall Islands","Mauritania","Mauritius","Mexico","Micronesia","Moldova","Monaco","Mongolia","Montenegro","Morocco","Mozambique",
                        "Namibia","Nauru","Nepal","Netherlands","New Zealand","Nicaragua","Niger","Nigeria","North Korea","Norway",
                        "Oman",
                        "Pakistan","Palau","Palestine","Panama","Papua New Guinea","Paraguay","Peru","Philippines","Poland","Portugal",
                        "Qatar"
                        "Republic of the Congo","Romania","Russia","Rwanda",
                        "Saint Kitts and Nevis","Saint Lucia","Saint Vincent and the Grenadines","Samoa","San Marino","Sao Tome and Principe","Saudi Arabia","Senegal","Serbia","Seychelles","Sierra Leone","Singapore","Slovakia","Slovenia","Solomon Islands","Somalia","South Africa","South Korea","South Sudan","Spain","Sri Lanka","Sudan","Suriname","Swaziland","Sweden","Switzerland","Syria",
                        "Taiwan","Tajikistan","Tanzania","Thailand","Timor-Leste","Togo","Tonga","Trinidad and Tobago","Tunisia","Turkey","Turkmenistan","Tuvalu",
                        "Uganda","Ukraine","United Arab Emirates","United Kingdom","United States of America","Uruguay","Uzbekistan",
                        "Vanuatu","Venezuela","Vietnam",
                        "Yemen",
                        "Zambia","Zimbabwe"};

    string  Stored[SIZE] = {""};                       

    string combination; 

    int i = 0, j = 0;

    while(combination != "#") {

    cout << "Enter in a two letter combination to be searched in the world's countries." << endl;
    cin >> combination;

    j = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {

        if(combination == Countries[i]) {
            Stored[j] = Countries[i];
            j++;
        }

    }

    cout << "The countries with " << combination << " are: ";

    for(j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {

        cout << Stored[j] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "To exit type #" << endl;
    cin >> combination;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Um... use a loop and std::string::find() on each element...?

Comment: Read up on the "trie" data structure

Comment: A trie is overkill for n < 300.

Comment: Regex is always an option.

Comment: You get all the countries matching that text or exactly one country? I have to ask it changes answer based on it

Comment: https://xkcd.com/208/

Comment: @Dúthomhas how would I use std::string::find() in this situation?

Comment: @Dúthomhas You have a good point, sir. Good reading all the same.

Comment: [Docs for `std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) `std::find_if` may be more useful to you here.

Comment: Use a Trie / Prefix Tree. That is how this sort of problem is commonly solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through all the potential matches.
Test each one for a match.
If it matches, add it to your list of matched items.

```
string string_to_find = "an";

for (auto country : Countries)
  if (country.find( string_to_find ) != country.npos)
    Stored[number_stored++] = country;
```

Comment: even if it'd a valid answer I'd recommend to explain your code ... ehm...  better?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string::find(const string&)` like this:

```
if (Countries[i].find(combination) != std::string::npos) {
```

replace your condition `if(combination == Countries[i]) {` with that one to search inside the string content

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::copy_if`:

```
auto end = std::copy_if( std::begin( Countries ), std::end( Countries ), std::begin( Stored ), [combination]( const std::string &ct ) {
    return ct.find( combination ) != std::string::npos;
} );
```

then matching countries will be in `[std::begin( Stored ),end[` range.

this code though may not work for uppercase letters, but it is pretty simple to change that, for example replace `std::string::find()` with your own, that ignores case.

Comment: I'm sure he won't understand this answer, even if its the "more optimized" one

Comment: @IvanSanz even so, answers for community, not only for OP